# Salesforce extract substring from string with regex

Tags: regex, string, salesforce, match, apex

I am developing an application in `Salesforce` with `Apex` and i need to extract a `Substring` from other `string`. This is the original `String`:

```
String str = 'Product: Multi Screen Encoder Version: 3.51.10 (008) Order Number: 0030000a9Ddy Part Number: 99-00228-X0-Y-WW02-NA01 Comment: some comments';
```

i Want to extract the value of **`Part Number`** so i am using the `Matcher` and `Pattern classes`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('Part Number: (.+)\\s');
Matcher pm = p.matcher(str);    
if (pm.matches()) {
    res = 'match = ' + pm.group(1);
    System.debug(res);
} else {
    System.debug('No match');
}
```

But i am getting `No match`.

How can i fix the `regex` to match correctly my `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `find` function instead of `matches` in the `if` condition.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('Part Number: (\\S+)\\s');
Matcher pm = p.matcher(str);    
if (pm.find()) {
    res = 'match = ' + pm.group(1);
    System.debug(res);
} else {
    System.debug('No match');
}
```

`\\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

or

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('Part Number: (.+?)\\s');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried the first proposition and it works fine. i forgot in my question that i  need to match also `Version` but it has spaces .How can i extract the value: `3.51.10 (008)`. ??

Comment: @ihssan it's a tough part since the key also contains spaces.

Comment: you may try `Pattern p = Pattern.compile('Version: (\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+(?:\\s\\([^)]*\\))?)');`